# combined Input IP3 of an LNA+attenuator

Tags: rf

Does the combined  input IP3 of the LNA+Attenuator change with the attenuator setting  if the attenuator is placed after the LNA?

Comment: Why would an unspecified attenuator be assumed to contribute to IP3?

Comment: This is my question: if the nominal attenuation is say 0 dB and I increase it to say 5 dB would this affect the input IP3? (not the output IP3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the down-stream attenuator changes the operating point, at both DC and AC, of the LNA, there will be no change in the Input Referred Intercept points.